# Why does uncurling iOS partial curl only works when click limited part of curl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, page-curl

I have a partial curl on iPhone iOS 5 app and notice that when using partial curl transition undoing (uncurl) only happens when clicking certain limited area of the page "curl" - not the section nearest to what would be the bottom right corner.
This meant it took some time to realise that it actually did work at all - why is this it seems totally counter-intuitive?
And is there something I need to do to make the whole "curl" clickable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a trick.. In the second view, you put a hidden button in the place you want to dismiss. Then just use a code like this:

```
- (IBAction)toDismiss:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```